# Flex/Flash Builder : Proper way to reference another project?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, project-management, flash-builder, project

I have a fairly large Flex/Flash Builder project using Flash Builder 4.5.  I want to create another project that uses some of the components from that original project.  In the new project, I link resources with the original project and it works fine but the new project's file size is pretty large.  It's close to the original project's file size even though it only uses a fraction of the components and assets.  Is there a better way to do this to minimize the file size of the new project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely look at what compiling with `-link-report` flag does. This prints the dependency map and would've showed you why are you using that many resources.

If you don't know how to do it: there's a place where you can add compiler arguments in the project settings - usually FB adds -locale=en_US there (which you actually don't need probably), add -link-report=report.xml and compile. It will generate an xml file in the root directory of your project. Open it and examine.

http://www.kahunaburger.com/2008/03/08/air-link-report-visualizer/ I didn't use this program, but it seems to give nice visual representation of dependencies - could be also useful.

Comment: Never heard about `-link-report` before. +1 for that

Comment: Thanks, using -link-report, it appears that all the components and assets from the original project are being compiled as a dependency in the new project even though only a fraction of those are being used/referenced in the new project.  Is that just strictly the case when linking resources/projects in Flex/Flash Builder?  If so, is there a way to pick and choose specific components/files to reference from the original project to the new project?

Comment: It must be the way I'm linking/referencing the original project.  I'm using "Linked Resources" within the "Resources" property for the new project (Project B) and am linking to the src folder of Project A (the original).  That's compiling every component/asset in Project A.

Comment: Actually, it was a factory resource that I had been including that was compiling all of the components.  Fixed now and everything is good.  Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You should separate all the common, reusable code into one or more library projects. In FlashBuilder you cannot convert the nature of a project from application to library, so you'll have to create a blank library project and copy over the code that you want available in both projects.

In its simplest form you project structure should look like this:

```
Flex app project A (swf) \
                           Flex library project (swc)
Flex app project B (swf) /
```

Now to use that library, go to 'Properties > Flex Build Path', click the 'Add Project...' button and select the library project you just created.

[image: add library project]

Now that you've linked to that project, you want to choose how the referenced components will be linked. (Double click on 'link type' to edit.)

[image: choose link type]

With your way of linking your projects FB apparently just compiled all classes from project A into project B. That's obviously not what you want. These are your linkage options (for an application project):

- **merged into code**: only the code that is actually referenced will be compiled into the main application. So if ClassA from the lib project is never referenced and ClassB is, only ClassB will be compiled into the main application.
- **RSL**: nothing is compiled into the main application, but the library is loaded at runtime; completely, since we don't know which classes we are going to need. This library is cached on the client though, so you'll have the longer load time just once. The main application will be smaller than with 'merged' linkage.

Which option to choose depends on the situation and is entirely up to you. I suggest you play around to see the difference for yourself (use a real server, because on a local server you won't get a feel for the loading times).

I should also mention there is the **external** linkage option, which doesn't compile any classes into the main app and also doesn't load them at runtime. This is primarily used for dependencies between libraries that will be used as RSL's in the same main application.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful.  Creating a swc library project is definitely the long term answer.  For the short term, to get this much smaller, new project up, do you know if there is there any way to pick and choose specific components/assets to link from project A to project B?  Like you said, the current way FB is linking projects is compiling all classes from project A to project B.

Comment: How are you linking to the other project's resources exactly? I didn't get that from your question.

Comment: I'm using "Linked Resources" within the "Resources" property for the new project (Project B) and am linking to the src folder of Project A.

Comment: Doesn't look like you can select specific classes in that case. Anyway, moving things into a separate library project shouldn't be too big of a task.